# Rspec controller test fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, controller

i'm trying to run such test:

```
 it "render form to update an bundle with a specific id" do
   bundle = mock_model(Bundle)
   Bundle.stub!(:find).with("1") { bundle }

   get :edit, :locale => "en", :id => 1
   Bundle.should_receive(:find).with("1").and_return(bundle)
 end
```

Code from a Controller:

```
class BundlesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /bundles
  # GET /bundles.json
  .....

  # GET /bundles/1/edit
  def edit
    @bundle = Bundle.find(params[:id])
  end
  .....
end
```

But test fails with message:

BundlesController Bundle update render form to update an bundle with a specific id
     Failure/Error: Bundle.should_receive(:find).with("1").and_return(bundle)
       ().find("1")
           expected: 1 time
           received: 0 times
     # ./spec/controllers/bundles_controller_spec.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in '

Can anyone helps me? 
Thanks!

Comment: There's no proof for us to go on that the controller actually has an edit action, or that the edit action has a call to `Bundle.find`. Show us more code, please.

Comment: My guess: Use a string `"1"` in stead of an integer `1`: `:id => "1"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here, and maybe more as you post more of your code.

First of all, you're setting up stubs and expectations on `Bundle` and then showing us code that loads a `Role` instead.

Second, you're calling `#should_receive` at the end of your test. This method sets up an expectation for code that comes after it in your test. Unless you have some hidden callback that you're not showing us, this is always going to fail. Reverse the order.

```
Bundle.should_receive(:find).with("1").and_return(bundle)
get :edit, :locale => "en", :id => 1
```